# How to bind with a different port

Tags: java, bind, rmi

I am trying to bind an object to a name using a different port than default, which is `1099`. I am using `Naming.bind`.

```
Naming.bind("myserver", server);
```

I have tried all these and I always get a `java.net.MalformedURLException`:

```
Naming.bind("myserver:2020", server);

Naming.bind("localhost:2020/myserver", server);

Naming.bind("//localhost:2020/myserver", server);
```

How can I do it? I've looked for information everywhere and I am surprised there's nothing said about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, with the third option, replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

A MalformedURLException is thrown when either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed.

Comment: Try with replacing why? There is no difference.

Comment: The former is a hostname and the latter is an IP address, but you already know that. In a distant past, I recall that I experienced problems a few times resolving `localhost` because it was not in the hosts file. Considering that I would not expect a `MalformedURLException` for the third attempt reported (the javadoc for which you mentioned the existence suggests to pass an URL without the "scheme component", that is `//host:port/name`), I believe that might've been why I answered that, more than six years ago, but I honestly don't remember...

Comment: ... That being said, I would not expect a `MalformedURLException` for a non-resolvable host, but instead a `UnknownHostException`, so that hypothesis ought to be wrong, but for some reason the method does not declare that exception. So there must be something I misunderstand here, but I don't really care about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 Naming.bind("rmi://localhost:2020/myserver", server);
```

I don't know where you looked, but MalformedURLException does have Javadoc.